# Cycle does not work

Tags: python

I was writing a simple program in Python. Firstly, user inputs some data. If the data equals to 'y', then the cycle starts

```
ans = raw_input()
if ans.lower() == 'y':
      for path in mas[]:
           print("This is cycle")
           function()
      print("End of program")
```

The problem is that terminal outputs only "End of program". Neither the function nor the output of the text in the loop does not work.

Comment: What is `mas[]`?

Comment: look like mas[] is empty.

Comment: You should not be learning Python 2 in 2018. By the original timetable, it would be end-of-lifed already. The currently supported and recommended version of the language is Python 3.

Comment: `mas[]` is a syntax error, but it sounds like you are just trying to iterate over an empty list, either `[]` or `mas` defined with `mas = []`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but mas [] is not empty, there are three elements in it. What Freeman suggested worked.

Comment: The point is that you can compare to `mas`, not `mas[]`; and that we can't help you with code we can't see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's very easy, you can do it like this :

```
while True:
    cont = raw_input("Another one? yes/no > ")
    if cont == "no":
        print("End of program")
        break
    if cont == "yes":
        print("This is cycle")
```

If you use Python3 change `raw_input` to `input`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked